# Adding matplotlib charts to Excel sheets in for loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, openpyxl

I have an Excel file with multiple sheets. With the data I retrieve from another Excel file, I want to add `matplotlib` charts to each sheet. However, although the plots are generated and shown in the console while the loop runs, once the loop is finished, all the sheets have the last chart added; the one that's supposed to be added to the last sheet.

I tried breaking down the loop and going manually, e.g., plot scheme for sheet[0], for sheet[1], etc. This gave the same result. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or this is some sort of bug in openpyxl.

```py
sheets = wb.sheetnames

for i in range(0, len(sheets)):
    #Iterate over sheets
    ws = wb[sheets[i]]


    #The chart code
    . . .

#I save the current plot to be added to the Excel sheet using openpyxl
    fig1.savefig("myplot.png", dpi = 72) 


#Add the saved chart to the active excel sheet, which is the current iteration in the loop
    img = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image('myplot.png')
    ws.add_image(img)

wb.save('Excel_file.xlsx')
```

At each iteration a new chart is supposed to be added to the active sheet. But I get the last chart in all of them at the end.

The Excel file with the charts added is supposed to be the final form of a fully automated report. I am not using `openpyxl`'s charts instead of `matplotlib` because I need the flexibility and customizability of the latter.

Any help is appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: do you try to save each chart with different name? It looks like all images refer to same file when loaded/saved.

Comment: But why doesn't it work like this in the first place? Once an iteration, let's say `i=2`, is near to finishing, `worksheet[2]` gets appended with `chart[2]`. Then the iteration ends and now `i=3`. Why does `worksheet[2]` become active somehow when `i=3`.

Comment: it's a guess, but probably it just creates reference to the png file named  myplot.png and the actual file is added to xlsx file only when you save the xlsx file. at that time the image is the last chart. so you have the same image on all worksheets (they all refer to  myplot.png). Again, just a guess but it's worth to test it.

Comment: I actually tried to save the file everytime in the loop too and I faced the same problem. It's odd. However, your solution worked so thanks!